# How to silence warnings in return variables when they are not used?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, data-types, local-variables, warnings

I have the following function in `solidity`:

```
function validateAndPayForPaymasterTransaction(
    bytes32, 
    bytes32, 
    Transaction calldata _transaction
) external payable override onlyBootloader returns (bytes4 magic, bytes memory context) {
    require(
        _transaction.paymasterInput.length >= 4,
        "The standard paymaster input must be at least 4 bytes long"
    );

    bytes4 paymasterInputSelector = bytes4(
        _transaction.paymasterInput[0:4]
    );
    if (paymasterInputSelector == IPaymasterFlow.approvalBased.selector) {
        (address token, uint256 minAllowance, ) = abi
            .decode(
                _transaction.paymasterInput[4:],
                (address, uint256, bytes)
            );

        require(token == allowedToken, "Invalid token");
        require(minAllowance >= 1, "Min allowance too low");

        address userAddress = address(uint160(_transaction.from));
        address thisAddress = address(this);

        uint256 providedAllowance = IERC20(token).allowance(
            userAddress,
            thisAddress
        );
        require(
            providedAllowance >= PRICE_FOR_PAYING_FEES,
            "The user did not provide enough allowance"
        );

        // Note, that while the minimal amount of ETH needed is tx.gasPrice * tx.gasLimit,
        // neither paymaster nor account are allowed to access this context variable.
        uint256 requiredETH = _transaction.gasLimit *
            _transaction.maxFeePerGas;

        // Pulling all the tokens from the user
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(userAddress, thisAddress, 1);
        // The bootloader never returns any data, so it can safely be ignored here.
        (bool success, ) = payable(BOOTLOADER_FORMAL_ADDRESS).call{
            value: requiredETH
        }("");
        require(success, "Failed to transfer funds to the bootloader");
    } else {
        revert("Unsupported paymaster flow");
    }
}
```

I am getting these warnings in both variables that are being returned from the function (`bytes4 magic, bytes memory context`):

```
Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
```

How can I silence this warning? I cannot actually remove the variables since they are part of an override function. If I do that I would get the following:

```
Overriding function return types differ.
```

Comment: You just need to remove the variable name. So change `returns (bytes4 magic, bytes memory context)` to `returns (bytes4 magic, bytes memory)`.

Comment: If I do that I get: `Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to these warnings is:

Remove the name of the variables from the `return` statement, as
suggested by
[shubhamskatel](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/99448/shubhamskatel):

```
function validateAndPayForPaymasterTransaction(
    bytes32, 
    bytes32, 
    Transaction calldata _transaction
) external payable override onlyBootloader returns (bytes4, bytes memory)
```

And then make sure that you are actually returning the said value types in every `return` of your code (all non-reverting code paths):

```
return (paymasterInputSelector, bytesVariable);
```

In this example, `paymasterInputSelector` is of type `bytes4` and `bytesVariable` is of type `bytes`.

**Note** - you declare a `bytes` variable like this:

```
        bytes memory bytesVariable = new bytes(0);
```